# Trying to get Login field from the popup which has "Register" and "Login" both form on same popup .error occurred- expression must be array type

Tags: selenium-webdriver

error occure -The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to By
how to get the exact xpath as this one is working perfectly fine on application console

for
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@tabindex='-1']")[1]);
login.click();

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.